# react-native-share not working properly in android version 7 and more?

Tags: android, react-native, share

I am working on react-native-share in my app. The share options are working fine till the android version 5. I am not sure its working fine in version 6.

But I am sure share is not working in version 7 and above. What will be the issue. I ate my entire day. I have tried to change the versions

my share code is

```
_downloadImageAndShare(url ,title, message) {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    RNFetchBlob.config({ fileCache: true })
      .fetch('GET', url)
      .then(resp => resp.readFile('base64')
          .then(base64 => ({ resp, base64 })))
      .then(obj => {
        const headers = obj.resp.respInfo.headers;
        const type = headers['Content-Type'];
        const dataUrl = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + obj.base64;
        return { url: dataUrl, title, message };
      })
      .then(options => {
        Share.open(options)
        this.setState({loading: false})
      });        
   }
```

and also

```
<uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="16"
            android:targetSdkVersion="26" /> 



android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.uplode"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

But it didn't get work. The exact issues are (in android 7 version):    **

```
1. whatsapp not even opening while trigger share button.
2. Hangouts only allows to share the url and message, not allowing to share image.
3. E-mail also the same scenario of hangouts
```

**   what should i do now? thanks in advance

Comment: [Reference : React-native share Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082623/react-native-share-promise-rejection-error/49549231#49549231)

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn't allow images to share in android. when i send image url it just sending the plain url. then only i choose this npm react-native-share, then i converted the image url to base64 format by react-native-fetch-blob@SyedZainAli

Comment: Sharing base64 image fails on android API 23 and higher if permissions has not been requested.   https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/pull/244

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a permission issue for API 23 and higher. Try this quick fix below.

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

...

async _downloadImageAndShare(url ,title, message) {
this.setState({loading: true})

const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
  'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
 );
 if (!granted) {
  const response = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
  );
  if (!response) {
    return;
  }
 }

RNFetchBlob.config({ fileCache: true })
  .fetch('GET', url)
  .then(resp => resp.readFile('base64')
      .then(base64 => ({ resp, base64 })))
  .then(obj => {
    const headers = obj.resp.respInfo.headers;
    const type = headers['Content-Type'];
    const dataUrl = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + obj.base64;
    return { url: dataUrl, title, message };
  })
  .then(options => {
    Share.open(options)
    this.setState({loading: false})
  });        

}
```

This fix will check if the needed permission is active before attempting to share base64 image to WhatsApp. You can [read more on the issue here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/pull/244)

Comment: It's also worth noting that this only worked for me when requesting permission at runtime, like above. Adding a permission line to the manifest didn't work for me.